# R library for R-tree implementation

Tags: r, tree, cluster-analysis

I have data frame, for example

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:1e3, y = rnorm(1e3))
```

I need to split points on N (in my case N = 6, 12 and 24) rectangles with equal number of points. How to split my df using [R-tree algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)?

Comment: Do you confirm that overlaps are allowed? Otherwise 1e3 should be a multiple of N

Comment: Overlaps are allowed

Comment: R-tree doesn't guarantee that the number of point in each rectangle are equal : which version of the algorithm are you thinking about? Are you looking for equal number of points or almost equal?

Comment: I'm looking for almost equal number of points

Comment: Perhaps a starting point, but needs extra development to answer your question : https://github.com/hunzikp/rtree

Comment: Can the rectangles be rotated? Or do they need to be parallel to the axes?

Comment: Rectangles can be rotated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uniformely distributed data on the x axis, `kmeans` clustering works (without surprise) well:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:1e3, y = rnorm(1e3))

N <- 10
df$cluster <- kmeans(df,N)$cluster

cluster_rectangles <- df %>% group_by(cluster) %>% 
       summarize(xmin = min(x),
                 xmax = max(x),
                 ymin = min(y),
                 ymax = max(y),
                 n = n())  

ggplot() + geom_rect(data = cluster_rectangles, mapping=aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, fill=cluster)) +
           geom_point(data = df,mapping=aes(x,y),color='white')
```

[image]
It also works if x distribution is normal :

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1e3), y = rnorm(1e3))
```

[image]
Drawback is that the number of points for each rectangle varies :

```
> cluster_rectangles %>% select(cluster,n)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   cluster     n
     <int> <int>
 1       1   137
 2       2    58
 3       3   121
 4       4    61
 5       5    72
 6       6   184
 7       7    78
 8       8    70
 9       9   126
10      10    93
```

For an uniform distribution, the result is quite good (with N=9):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case that **all the points have different x coordinates**, as it is the case in your example, sort the points increasingly according to the x coordinate. Note that, in this case, your problem of finding a covering with rectangles (with equal number of points) for the 2d points can be simplified to finding a covering with segments for 1d points (i.e. you can ignore the height of the rectangles).

Here how you can find the points in each rectangle:

```
num_rect <- 7 # In your example 6, 12 or 24
num_points <- 10 # In your example 1e3

# Already ordered according to x
df <- data.frame(x = 1:num_points, y = rnorm(num_points))

# Minimum number of points in the rectangles to cover all of them
points_in_rect <- ceiling(num_points/num_rect)

# Cover the first points using non-overlaping rectangles
breaks <- seq(0,num_points, by=points_in_rect)
cover <- split(seq(num_points), cut(seq(num_points), breaks))
names(cover) <- paste0("rect", seq(length(cover)))

# Cover the last points using overlaping rectangles
cur_num <- length(cover)
if (num_points < num_rect*points_in_rect ) {
  # To avoid duplicate rectangles
  last <- num_points
  if (num_points %% 1 == 0)
    last <- last -1

  while (cur_num < num_rect) {
    cur_num <- cur_num + 1
    new_rect <- list(seq(last-points_in_rect+1, last))
    names(new_rect) <- paste0("rect", cur_num)
    cover <- c(cover,new_rect)
    last <- last - points_in_rect
  }
}
```

The points in the rectangles are:

```
$rect1
[1] 1 2

$rect2
[1] 3 4

$rect3
[1] 5 6

$rect4
[1] 7 8

$rect5
[1]  9 10

$rect6
[1] 8 9

$rect7
[1] 6 7
```

The minimum bounding rectangles (parallel to the axes) that enclose those set of points are the ones that you are finding.

## Duplicated coordinate values in both axes

Randomly rotate the points (save the rotation angle) and check if there are not duplicate x (or y) coordinates. If this is the case, use the above strategy with the rotated coordinates (remember to sort before the rotated points according to the new x coordinates), and then rotate back the obtained rectangles in the opposite direction. If duplicated coordinates remain in both axes, rotate the points again with a different (random) angle. Since you have a finite number of points, you can always find a rotation angle that separates de x (or y) coordinates.